# Grid scrolling after render ZK

Tags: grid, zk

I'm trying to scroll down to the bottom of a grid, after the model was setted.

1) I set the model:

```
myGrid.setModel(new ListModelList<Object>(myList));
```

2) I override the row renderer

```
myGrid.setRowRenderer(new RowRenderer<Object>() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void render(Row row,final Object data, int index) throws Exception {                    
            row.setStyle("commonCellPadding");
                            .
                            .
                            .

            row.appendChild(htmlMessage);
        }           
    });
```

3) Finally if the list used to set the model is too big (the grid in the .zul has fixed height) i want to show the last results (the more recents in this case).
I need to scroll down automatically after the render. How can i do this?

Things i had try

a) Calling a javascript function after the render, this doesn't work due to the fact that the gridEle.scrollHeight attribute returns the fixed height of the grid  setted in the zul (or 0 if not) and not the grid's height after the model was setted.

```
myGrid.addEventListener(ZulEvents.ON_AFTER_RENDER, new EventListener<Event>() {
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception
        {

            Clients.evalJavaScript("var gridEle = document.getElementById('"+myGrid.getUuid()+"-body"+"'); gridEle.scrollTop = gridEle.scrollHeight;alert(gridEle.scrollHeight);");             
        }
    });
```

Comment: did you try below suggestion I made?

Comment: I tried but i didn't work out, maybe it's the Render-On-Demand, when i have some time off i'll keep researching.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you sort the myList descending at first to make the last row become the first one instead to control the scroll bar?
In my opinion, it would be more easy and matching the users experience.

Comment: The code is for a webchat, usually the last message recevied or sent is shown on the bottom of the window.
If the chat has a history (has already started an has messages) i want the window scrolled to bottom to show the last message in the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Clients.scrollIntoView(rows.getLastChild());` after you have set the model and row renderer (provided `rows` is Rows component id and is already auto wired into your controller). See the live demo on zkfiddle [here](http://zkfiddle.org/direct/22h1jqu/4/v6.0.1-scroll-grid-to-last-row-after-render?run=25man96) and [source](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/22h1jqu/4-scroll-grid-to-last-row-after-render)

**UPDATE**: `Clients.scrollIntoView(Component)` wouldn't work if you are using [Render-On-Demand](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Performance_Tips/Listbox,_Grid_and_Tree_for_Huge_Data/Turn_on_Render_on_Demand) feature because naturally if the row that you want to scroll to wouldn't have been loaded on initial page load.